# With the trueskill algorithm, given two players' ratings, how can I calculate the win/loss probability?

Tags: python, algorithm

I see this question come up a lot in discussions of trueskill, but I've yet to come across a conclusive answer.

I'm using the Python implementation here:

https://github.com/sublee/trueskill

I've put together a simple simulation using that library here:

https://gist.github.com/klenwell/3a15eca6b83ce575d0ca

The question is submitted as the [first issue](https://github.com/sublee/trueskill/issues/1) for the Python library. In the [Jeff Moser blog post](http://www.moserware.com/2010/03/computing-your-skill.html) which most trueskill discussions lead back to, the question comes up several times in the comments.

Can someone provide a function compatible with the Python library implementation that accurately returns a player's predicted win probability against another player based on the two players ratings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function based on [this comment](https://github.com/sublee/trueskill/issues/1#issuecomment-10491635) on the Moser blog:

```
from math import sqrt
from trueskill import BETA
from trueskill.backends import cdf

def win_probability(player_rating, opponent_rating):
    delta_mu = player_rating.mu - opponent_rating.mu
    denom = sqrt(2 * (BETA * BETA) + pow(player_rating.sigma, 2) + pow(opponent_rating.sigma, 2))
    return cdf(delta_mu / denom)
```

Tested with [my gist](https://gist.github.com/klenwell/3a15eca6b83ce575d0ca), this seems to perform better than original `win_probability` function found [here](https://github.com/sublee/trueskill/issues/1#issuecomment-10491635).

This function only handles the head-to-head case, but the comment includes a more general approach for calculating win probabilities for a multi-player match.